# Can package/class name be function parameter?

Tags: java, android, function, package

I have following code:

```
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;

...
builder = newBuilder(id, Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, bUpdate);
if (bPref) {
    builder.withValue(Email.TYPE, Email.TYPE_CUSTOM);
    builder.withValue(Email.LABEL, "PREF");
} else if (iType != -1) {
    builder.withValue(Email.TYPE, iType);
}
builder.withValue(Email.DATA, value);
ops.add(builder.build());

builder = newBuilder(id, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, bUpdate);
if (bPref) {
    builder.withValue(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_CUSTOM);
    builder.withValue(Phone.LABEL, "PREF");
} else if (iType != -1) {
    builder.withValue(Phone.TYPE, iType);
}
builder.withValue(Phone.DATA, value);
ops.add(builder.build());

builder = ...
...
```

These blocks are quite similar that I would like to write a function for them.

For example:

```
void build(xxx name) {
  ...
  if (bPref) {
    builder.withValue(name.TYPE, name.TYPE_CUSTOM);
    builder.withValue(name.LABEL, "PREF");
  } else if (iType != -1) {
    builder.withValue(name.TYPE, iType);
  }
  builder.withValue(name.DATA, value);
  ops.add(builder.build());
}

...
build(Email);
build(Phone);
build(...);
```

Or is there any way to refactor these into functions?

Comment: What are `Email` and `Phone`?

Comment: See the first two lines of my code. They are "android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email" and "android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone"

Comment: I am asking what type they are - class, Enum, package themselves? Or what? Your question currently is too vague to be answered. It doesn't contain enough information about the design to come up with some better alternative.

Comment: @RohitJain I'm new to Java so to be honest not sure what they are. According to [developers doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.html), looks like they are class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the only way I can figure out how to make it a function:

```
void build(String itemType, String fieldType, int typeCustom, String label, String data) {
}

...
build(Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, Email.TYPE, Email.TYPE_CUSTOM, Email.LABEL, Email.DATA);
build(Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_CUSTOM, Phone.LABEL, Phone.DATA);
build(Website.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, Website.TYPE, Website.TYPE_CUSTOM, Website.LABEL, Website.DATA);
```

It is not concise as I expected, but better than original repeating blocks.